# omnet++ 5.4.1 shows xml parser error in inet examples

Tags: omnet++, inet

i try to run Inet framework examples in omnet++ but i get this error and dont know how to solve it

> Error: Cannot evaluate parameter 'config': Cannot parse XML
>   string: XML input is not supported: this copy of OMNeT++ was compiled
>   without an XML parser (libXML or Expat) -- in module
>   (inet::Ipv4NetworkConfigurator) Net80211.configurator (id=3), during
>   network setup

Comment: Were you able to run "./configure" without any warning or error?

Comment: yes ./configure was run without error , i even installed expat and libxml but omnet cant find them

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error but I found a solution which might be useful. OMNeT++ IDE is not running on the same environment. Just choose the project file and right click "Run As > OMNeT++ simulation", it should run without an error.